# ionic facebook login on modal window

Tags: ios, facebook, ionic-framework

Hello I'm working on a Ionic app, my issue is that login with facebook app does not have a back button, that is not a problem on android because you have the hardware back button, but on IOS there is no way to go back, Is there a way to open this:

> window.loginFacebook();

On a modal window or inside my app? 
Sorry I'm pretty new to Ionic and really don't have a clue on native apps.
Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not. The FB login dialog has to be called in the top window instance, for the obvious reason that users need to be able to verify the content of the address bar, to prevent phishing. // _"android [has] the hardware back button, but on IOS there is no way to go back"_ - LOL, those Apple dudes are real geniuses, you have to give them that ...

Comment: Thanks sir. I'm doomed then :)